# Authorizing AWS APIGateway using Auth0 by custom authorizer approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, auth0, custom-authentication

The tech stacks are reactJS in the frontside and the backend is powered by APIGateway and Lambda. I am using Auth0 as Identity service in my react App. On authenticating through one of the social logins given by Auth0, I get back `access_token`, `id_token` and `expiry_time`. Further, I can get **User's Information** such as `emailId`using the `id_token`. Now, I need to protect/prevent access to my backend namely the APIGateway and Lambda.

There are lot of options to protect access to AWS APIGateway like **IAM authorizer**, **custom authorizer**. There is a Auth0 documentation on how to use [IAM authorizer with Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway). I would like to know, how to use custom authorizer. I understand the high level architecture of how custom authorizer works.

Here are my questions regarding custom authorizer:

**1Q.** By using react auth0 authentication module, I get back `access_token`, `id_token` and `expiry`. The received access_token is not a JWT. How to get a JWT access_token, so that I can pass it through Authorization header.

**2Q.** I see a separate section called **APIs** in Auth0 dashboard. This is highly confusing and ambiguous. In my understanding, this Auth0's API section require a separate call to Auth0 server and receive new access_token, which is different from social login's access token. Why can't I use the access token from react's Auth client?  I may be wrong, but I dont understand this API section in Auth0.

**3Q.** Assuming somehow, I send the access_token in the authorization header, how do I verify that in **custom authorizer's Lambda**. There are several blog posts on this, but each post follows a different approach. Some use `id_token` for verifying, others use `jwt package` to just decode, but I dont see a verification call to Auth0.

There are some blog posts on authorizing APIGateway with Auth0, but they are either old/deprecated or using some hacks to authorize it. It would be good, If we can document the proper method of authorizing an APIGateway using Auth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the above questions after having a talk with Auth0 support team. Here is the exhaustive guide that explains the APIGateway and Auth0 integration using custom Authorizer. https://github.com/lakshmantgld/auth0-APIGateway-CustomAuthorizer